# QSettings and sections containing spaces

Tags: qt, menu, char, settings, space

I use QSettings to edit the .desktop menu entries.
I do it like that: dfile is a QString - absolute file path

```
QSettings set(dfile, QSettings::IniFormat);
qDebug() << "Editing " << set.fileName();
set.beginGroup("Desktop Entry");
// set whatever I need
set.endGroup();
```

But when the .desktop file is saved, I get

```
[Desktop%20Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
# and etc.
```

instead of

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
# and etc.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong. The space is just encoded as %20 using [HTML URL encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). You can read the settings back, right?

Comment: And can the URL encoding be disabled? Yes I can read them. But the system doesn't recognize Desktop%20Entry, the icon in the menu is not displayed.